# Popular datagrid a partir de checkbox seleccionado en c#

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms

soy bastante nuevo en esto de la programación en C# y estoy realizando una aplicacion en la que me he tropezado con esta disgiuntiva, explico mi problema:
en la aplicacion en la que estoy trabajando tengo 2 WinForms: [image: WF principal] y [image: WF hijo]

y una clase para el manejo de datos a un DB en SQL Server. Ahora, en la clase ClsDtaMng tengo 2 datatables para popular el datagridview en WF hijo

```
    class ClsDtaMng
{    
            private ClsGlobal conn = new ClsGlobal();
        public DataTable ShowMaterials()
            {
    
                DataTable dbTable = new DataTable();
                SqlDataReader dbRead;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    
                try
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn.OpenConn();
                    cmd.CommandText = "select nameMaterial as Material,aliasMaterial as Alias,chemicMaterialname as Composition from tblMaterial";
                    dbRead = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    dbTable.Load(dbRead);
                    conn.CloseConn();
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    throw error;
                }
    
                return dbTable;
            }
    
            public DataTable ShowStandards()
            {
    
                DataTable dbTable = new DataTable();
                SqlDataReader dbRead;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    
                try
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn.OpenConn();
                    cmd.CommandText = "select tblStandards.clientStandardcode,tblStandards.descripStandard,tblSubCategory.descrpSubCat from (tblStandards inner join tblSubCategory on tblStandards.idSubCat = tblSubCategory.idSubCat); ";
                    dbRead = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    dbTable.Load(dbRead);
                    conn.CloseConn();
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    throw error;
                }
    
                return dbTable;
            }
```

,
en el WF hijo delcaro

```
public partial class FormSearch : Form
        {
        readonly ClsDtaMng dataCtrlMng = new ClsDtaMng();
    DataTable setMaterials = new DataTable();
    public FrmSearch(FrmCQ owner)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    
                Owner = owner;}
    
    private void FrmSearch_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                cmbxSearchcriteria.SelectedIndex = 1;
            }
    
            private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                switch (cmbxSearchcriteria.SelectedItem)
                {
                    default:
                        setMaterials.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"Composition like '{txtSearch.Text}%'";
                        break;
                    case "Material Name":
                        setMaterials.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"Material like '{txtSSearch.Text}%'";
                        break;
                }
            }
    
            private void btnSelectMaterial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ((FrmCQ)this.Owner)._nameMaterial = "Material: " + gdvwMaterials.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
                ActiveForm.Close();
            }
    
            private void gdvwMaterials_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    cmbxSearchcriteria.SelectedIndex = 0;
    
                    txtSearch.Text = gdvwMaterials.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(error.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
```

para la busqueda del material de acuerdo con el criterio seleccionado y después mostrarlo cono string en el textbox en el WF padre, y en el padre

```
private void chkbxPieceMaterial_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (chkbxPieceMaterial.Checked == true)
                {
                    FrmSearch frmSearch = new FrmSearch(this);
                    frmSearch.ShowDialog();

                    _notesCtrlList.Add(_nameMaterial.Trim());

                    UpdateNotesCtrl();
                }

                else
                {
                    _nameMaterial = string.Empty;
                }
            }

            catch(Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message.Trim());
            }
        }
```

Ahora, quisiera no tener que crear otro WF hijo para hacer la misma cosa cuando checho en el checkbox Standards ya que utilizaré la misma estructura para la busqueda de las normas (standards).

Agradezco en antícipo las sugerencias que me puedan dar, esperando poder encontrar una solución lo mas optimizada posible. Espero haya podido explicar bien el problema. Gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No tengo nada claro cual es el problema especifico que tenes

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por tu comentario, quice poner la mayor cantidad de datos acerca de mi problema posible pero al parecer lo compliqué aun más. El problema mio en si es que quiero utilizar solo un WF hijo (diseñado) para popular el datagridview a partir de la seleccion del checkbox en el WF padre, las query funzionan independientemente pero he probado varias vias y no encuentro todavia como pasar la query de forma dinamica al datagrid. Espero esta vez haya sido mas claro. Gracias

Comment: cada vez te entiendo menos.. vos queres seleccionar algo en un formulario, y despues llenar una grilla en otro formulario? es asi?

Comment: Cuando en el Form1 checo Material el datagridview se popula con valores en la tabla Material en DB en SQL Server, utilizando `public DataTable ShowMaterials()` (y esto me funsiona), ahora, lo que quisiera hacer es que cuando checo Standards el datagridview se popule con valores en la tabla Standards en DB utilizando `public DataTable ShowStandards()`. Gracias

Comment: Lo que quisiera evitar es repetir el codigo y diseñar otro form exactamente igual a FrmSearch, con las mismas caracteristicas y funsiones, solamente porque le estoy cambiando el Source del DataGridView (de `DataTable ShowMaterials()` a `DataTable ShowStandards()`. Gracias :'(

Comment: entonces pasale una variable al form que le diga que cargar

Answer (score 0):

Salvador es algo confuso el código pero traté de entender y creo que esto te pueda ayudar.

Simplemente realizar un select y parametriza el valor textSearch; yo cree 2 metodos y le envío donde obtiene el composition y el material:

```
        public DataTable BuscarMateriales(string material)
    {
        string strConsultaMaterial = "SELECT nameMaterial AS Material," +
                                       "aliasMaterial AS Alias, " +
                                       "chemicMaterialname AS Composition " +
                                       "FROM tblMaterial " +
                                       "WHERE nameMaterial like '%" +material + "'%";

        var TuDataTable = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strConsultaMaterial, con))
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                 
                 TuDataTable.Load(reader);
            }
        }

        return TuDataTable;
    }

    public DataTable BuscarComposition(string composition)
    {
        var TudataTable = new DataTable();
        string strConsultaComposition = "SELECT nameMaterial AS Material, aliasMaterial AS Alias," +
                                     " chemicMaterialname AS Composition FROM tblMaterial " +
                                     " WHERE Composition like '%" + composition+ "'%";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strConsultaComposition, con))
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                
                TudataTable.Load(reader);
            }
        }

        return TudataTable;
    }
```

Ya obtenido el resultado de tu consulta en DT realizar un
dgv.DataSource = BuscarMateriales() o dgv.DataSource =BuscarComposition()

Comment: gracias por tu comentario, es valido como referencia pero la solución que me propones está resuelta en el código que les muestro.

Answer (score 0):

Este comentario lo hago en parte para refinar la pregunta, en caso que pueda servir para después, y para dar la solución encontrada.

---

### Explicando la situación y refinando la pregunta:

**Situación**: Tengo la necesidad de crear un string a imprimir en el *TextBox* en **Form1**, con los valores escogidos de *Material* (CheckBox) y *Standard* (CheckBox).

TextBox.Text = string(*Material*) + string(*Standard*)

Al checkar *Material* se abre la ventana **FrmSearch** con la cual filtro y busco el material deseado a insertar en el *TextBox* antes mencionado.

**Nota:** la búsqueda y filtrado del material en la BD a través de la clase **ClsDtaMng**, y su posterior pasaje al *TextBox* lo soluciono con el código mostrado.

**Problema y pregunta**: Quisiera no tener que duplicar innecesariamente un **FrmSearch** donde lo único que cambia sería la query de búsqueda en la BD para buscar, filtrar los *Standards* y después pasarlo al *TextBox* en **Form1**.

**La solución:** Después de revisar varias posibles soluciones en linea, decidí que la solución más sencilla sería duplicar el Form para la busqueda (**FrmSearch**), en este caso sería complicar demasiado el código para obtener un resultado poco importante.

---

Agradezco a todos los que trataron de ayudarme, aún cuando entiendo que no estuve en grado de explicar mejor mi problema. Los saludo y espero hacerlo mejor para la próxima.